# adding new lvm mirror, all IOs only go to mirror

Tags: lvm

Here's an odd one. I added a mirror to a pre-existing disk in a vg using the standard mechanisms, and now, according to `iostat`, all I/O is only being serviced by the mirror. I'd expect writes to be going to both at the same rate.

original disk = `sdm`. new mirror = `sdn`, both disks have been present in machine for a while. Previously `sdn` was unused.

representative iostat numbers (not the first result:)

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sdm               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdn               0.00     0.00    0.00    9.00     0.00    45.33    10.07     0.01    1.37    0.00    1.37   1.37   1.23
```

---

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sdm > /tmp/x
sfdisk /dev/sdn < /tmp/x
pvcreate /dev/sdn2
vgextend cl /dev/sdn2
lvconvert -m 1 cl/root
lvconvert -m 1 cl/home
lvconvert -m 1 cl/dpoolzil
lvconvert -m 1 cl/flashimages
```

Any ideas on this oddity?

-- **update 8/15/2017** --
machine needed to be totally reinstalled as OS was irrevocably stuck (comments).

machine back online. I left the disk partitioning exactly the same as it was before and after the OS install (cent7.3), it detected the other pvs, booted properly, and I got all the zfs data back, but the original cause of this is still troubling. The mirroring does appear to be working now (based upon iostat showing same numbers from sdn/sdm). Also, sfdisk output on both looks fine. Any suggestions on other things to check to triple-verify that it's all good? lvs, pvs, vgs, all look pretty sane.

```
[root@vm1 doug]# vgs
  VG #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree  
  cl   2   5   0 wz--n- 1.82t 380.98g
[root@vm1 doug]# lvs
  LV          VG Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  dpoolzil    cl rwi-aor---   8.00g                                    100.00          
  flashimages cl rwi---r--- 600.00g                                                    
  home        cl rwi-a-r---  80.00g                                    100.00          
  root        cl rwi-aor---  50.00g                                    100.00          
  swap        cl -wi-a-----   4.00g                                                    
[root@vm1 doug]# pvs
  PV         VG Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  
  /dev/sdm2  cl lvm2 a--  930.51g 188.49g
  /dev/sdn2  cl lvm2 a--  930.51g 192.49g
[root@vm1 doug]# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/cl/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                cl
  LV UUID                W7TV8r-RGSi-Lcj7-B50m-xxlx-6XUA-DxpmXQ
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time vm1.kestonenap.net, 2017-04-14 22:16:17 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                4.00 GiB
  Current LE             1024
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:5

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/cl/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                cl
  LV UUID                KKepXa-GvJh-3vxE-3Jja-yhca-ecsX-xiKNDD
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time vm1.kestonenap.net, 2017-04-14 22:16:17 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                80.00 GiB
  Current LE             20480
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:10

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/cl/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                cl
  LV UUID                guSfCa-B07B-wPXO-pX76-Rx2b-d95d-FEMVBy
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time vm1.kestonenap.net, 2017-04-14 22:16:18 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                50.00 GiB
  Current LE             12800
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:4

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/cl/flashimages
  LV Name                flashimages
  VG Name                cl
  LV UUID                URVi35-SUGe-m8I8-UbVw-BtRz-Wdi4-QvI8E7
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time vm1.kestonenap.net, 2017-04-15 13:38:46 -0400
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                600.00 GiB
  Current LE             153600
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/cl/dpoolzil
  LV Name                dpoolzil
  VG Name                cl
  LV UUID                LIAHNK-lHac-Ua7c-c0o8-vHlB-h6w3-SF4D3m
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time vm1.kestonenap.net, 2017-04-15 13:49:44 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                8.00 GiB
  Current LE             2048
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:19

iostat interval paste:
sdm               0.00     0.00    0.00    6.00     0.00    18.67     6.22     0.01    1.72    0.00    1.72   1.06   0.63
sdn               0.00     0.00    0.00    6.00     0.00    18.67     6.22     0.01    1.61    0.00    1.61   1.00   0.60
```

Comment: How do things look with lsblk?

Comment: it appears now that my OS is corrupted. common apps like virsh, zpool, zfs are now failing with segfault. lsblk is also segfaulting. Something appears to have gone dreadfully wrong in the mirror, but I don't see any missing steps or errors in my process.

Comment: What is dmesg reporting?

Comment: I've also just realised something. After you dumped partition table with sfdisk, did you amend all the sdm references to sdn before reading it back to the sdn device? If not, I would say that this is your problem.

Comment: Raman, it's an interesting theory. I checked the partitioning on sdn after running the sfdisk < and it looked correct and accurate.

Comment: Also, the machine is offline and no longer usable at the moment. Won't boot up fully. There was lots of messages about xfs corruption on the console, but it's all gone now. Somehow, it got toasted.

Comment: machine back online. I left the disk partitioning exactly the same as it was before and after the OS install (cent7.3), it detected the other pvs, booted properly, and I got all the zfs data back, but the original cause of this is still troubling. The mirroring does appear to be working now (based upon iostat showing same numbers from sdn/sdm). Also, sfdisk output on both looks fine.
Any suggestions on other things to check to triple-verify that it's all good? lvs, pvs, vgs, all look pretty sane.